# Json request to google geocoding api not being parsed

Tags: google-geolocation

I am attempting to utilize the google geocoding api in order to find the coordinates of devices using their cell id, location area code, mobile country code and their mobile network code. Unfortunately my requests are getting a code 400 parse error from google's geocoding api when I test it using CURL.
This is my JSON code:

```
{
"homeMobileCountryCode": 242,
"homeMobileNetworkCode": 1,
"radioType": "gsm",  
"considerIp": "false",
"cellTowers": [
    "cellId": 41010,
    "locationAreaCode": 2862,
    "mobileCountryCode": 242,
    "mobileNetworkCode": 1,            
  ],  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json is invalid. Didn't you mean to format it like this:

```
{
    "homeMobileCountryCode": 242,
    "homeMobileNetworkCode": 1,
    "radioType": "gsm",
    "considerIp": "false",
    "cellTowers": {
        "cellId": 41010,
        "locationAreaCode": 2862,
        "mobileCountryCode": 242,
        "mobileNetworkCode": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, turns out the commas were the problem.

Comment: @NotRealName yes, as I guess you already saw, I removed the wrong commas in the answer